# Lifecycle event not working for non aggregate entity Spring Data JDBC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I am using two entities, *Employee* and *Address*, where *Employee* has the controller to do CRUD operations. So for both the entities I am using lifecycle events where *Employee* events are working fine but not the *Address* events. So I am trying to save *Employee* which has *Address* in it (one to one relations) and expecting *Employee* and *Address* both lifecycle events to get trigger.

Please help me.
Am I doing wrong anywhere?

Here is my code.

```
@Table("EMPLOYEE")
@Builder // these are lombok code
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
public class Employee {

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String updatedBy;
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
    private Date dob;
    @Size(max = 10)
    private String name;
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedOn;
    @Version
    private Long version;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdOn;
    private Integer age;
    @Valid
    private Address address;
}
```

```
@Table("ADDRESS")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
public class Address {
    private Integer zip;
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 10)
    @NotNull
    private String line1;
}
```

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController
{
//CRUD APIs code
}
```

```
@Component
public class EmployeeEvents
    extends AbstractRelationalEventListener<Employee>
{
    @Override
    protected void onBeforeSave(BeforeSaveEvent event) {
        System.out.println("........"+ event.getEntity());

    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class AddressEvents
    extends AbstractRelationalEventListener<Address>
{
    @Override
    protected void onBeforeSave(BeforeSaveEvent event) {
        System.out.println("........"+ event.getEntity());

    }
}
```

EDIT 1:
Data getting saved properly. All I want is events to get trigger. And since it's *Spring Data* JDBC one to one will work without any extra annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lifecycle events and callbacks only get fired for aggregates.

Part of the design rule for aggregates says that you should access entities internal to an aggregate only by the aggregate.
This would be violated when Spring Data JDBC hands out references to such entities to a listener or callback.

So the correct solution is to listen to `BeforeSaveEvent` for the aggregate root, i.e. `Employee` and access the `Address` via the `Employee`.

Answer (score 0):

do OneToOne Mapping with Address entity and than try

Example of a one-to-one relationship, in this case between user and address entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    //... 

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;

    // ... getters and setters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    //...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private User user;

    //... getters and setters
}
```

Comment: this is spring data jdbc not jpa. so the relations works differently here